# Javascript replace all "%20" with a space

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to replace every "%20" with a space using JavaScript. I know how to replace a single "%20" with a space but how do I replace all of them?

```
var str = "Passwords%20do%20not%20match";   
var replaced = str.replace("%20", " "); // "Passwords do%20not%20match"
```

Comment: You can use `window.decodeURIComponent()`, it will convert more than just '%20' though.

Comment: No, this isn't an exact duplicate.  There is a deeper issue, and there is an answer here that successfully addresses that issue.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Check this out:
[How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Short answer:

```
str.replace(/%20/g, " ");
```

EDIT:
In this case you could also do the following:

```
decodeURI(str)
```

Answer (score 81):

The percentage `%` sign followed by two hexadecimal numbers *(UTF-8 character representation)* typically denotes a string which has been encoded to be part of a *URI*.  This ensures that characters that would otherwise have special meaning don't interfere.  In your case `%20` is immediately recognisable as a whitespace character - while not *really* having any meaning in a *URI* it is encoded in order to avoid breaking the string into multiple "parts".

Don't get me wrong, [regex is the bomb](http://xkcd.com/208/)! However any web technology worth caring about will already have tools available in it's library to handle [***standards***](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) like this for you.  Why re-invent the wheel...?

```js
var str = 'xPasswords%20do%20not%20match';
console.log( decodeURI(str) ); // "xPasswords do not match"
```

Javascript has both [`decodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) and [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) which differ slightly in respect to their [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) and [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) counterparts - you should familiarise yourself with the documentation.

Comment: I'm surprised to see that this is the only answer not trying to actually replace things in the string. This is the proper way to handle this situation.

Comment: It doesn't work in url hash in react . I tried both encode and decode none of these effect in browser url .

window.location.hash = decodeURI(tab);

http://localhost:5173/#new%20abc%20abc%20abc

Answer (score 14):

Use the `global` flag in regexp:

```
var replaced = str.replace(/%20/g, " ");
                                ^
```

Answer (score 10):

using `unescape(stringValue)`

```js
var str = "Passwords%20do%20not%20match%21";
document.write(unescape(str))
```

```
//Output
Passwords do not match!
```

---

use `decodeURI(stringValue)`

```js
var str = "Passwords%20do%20not%20match%21";
 document.write(decodeURI(str))
```

```
Space = %20
? = %3F
! = %21
# = %23
...etc
```

Comment: `decodeURIComponent` will work as expected, the use of `unescape` should not be recommended - please refer to the giant red warning at the top of the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) for more details.

Answer (score 9):

This method uses the `decodeURIComponent()` function, which is the most reliable one.

```js
var str = "Passwords%20do%20not%20match%21";
var replaced = decodeURIComponent(str);  // "Passwords do not match"

console.log(replaced);
```

Here are some characters it replaces:

```
%20 to <space>
%3F to "?"
%21 to "!"
%23 to "#"
etc...
```

There's a good example of this at the Mozilla docs [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI].

Please note that if you ONLY want to replace "%20", use the `replaceAll` function instead:

```js
var str = "Passwords%20do%20not%20match";   
var replaced = str.replaceAll("%20", " "); // "Passwords do not match";

console.log(replaced)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`.replaceAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/)

Comment: btw replaceAll works without jquery

Answer (score -2):

If you need to remove white spaces at the end then here is a solution:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/urlify-given-string-replace-spaces/

```js
const stringQ1 = (string)=>{
  //remove white space at the end 
  const arrString = string.split("")
  for(let i = arrString.length -1 ; i>=0 ; i--){
    let char = arrString[i];
    
    if(char.indexOf(" ") >=0){
     arrString.splice(i,1)
    }else{
      break;
    }
  }

  let start =0;
  let end = arrString.length -1;
  

  //add %20
  while(start < end){
    if(arrString[start].indexOf(' ') >=0){
      arrString[start] ="%20"
      
    }
    
    start++;
  }
  
  return arrString.join('');
}

console.log(stringQ1("Mr John Smith   "))
```