# Replace %20 with space in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am currently working with a form in html, passing form data from one html form to another. When displaying the data I am getting `%20` in the place of every space. Is there a way to replace this?

My code in the receiving page is:

```
<script type = "text/javascript"> 
    document.write("Business Name:  ", BusinessName);<-- Variables that are passed through URL-->
    document.write("Business Type:  ", BusinessType);
    document.write("Business Purpose:  ", BusinessPurpose);
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792572/javascript-replace-all-20-with-a-space

Comment: hi you need to decode the data

Comment: @Venom, dear god... that accepted answer is so bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`unescape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape)

Your string is url encoded. just `unescape` it.

```
unescape("asd%20asd")
-> "asd asd"
```

Comment: where do i write this function? thanks

Comment: I am not sure how to use this function, or where to implement it. Thnks. I hve tried: unescape.document.write("Business Name:  ", BusinessName+"<br><br>");

Comment: document.write("Business Name: ", unescape(BusinessName)+"<br><br>");