# How to Remove Junk fields in text

Tags: javascript

Is there a standard function to remove the junk symbols in the text
var a= "CWC%20-%20Maint%20Eng%20-%20El"
which is instead to be displayed as CWC - Maint Eng - El

Comment: Try `decodeURIComponent("CWC%20-%20Maint%20Eng%20-%20El");`. Search before you post.

Comment: Please, edit your question and add the desired result

Comment: @alessadro -- **CWC - Maint Eng - El** was the desired result.

Comment: Then try the code in the 31piy's comment, is exact you need

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript replace all "%20" with a space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792572/javascript-replace-all-20-with-a-space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use replace function, and make the string replace as a global, check here [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dy4ztxmq/)

```
var str = 'CWC%20-%20Maint%20Eng%20-%20El';
str = str.replace(/%20/g, " ");
console.log(str);
```

or you can use decodeURIComponent method

```
var str = 'CWC%20-%20Maint%20Eng%20-%20El';
var de_str = decodeURIComponent(str);
console.log(de_str);
```